# Is there any way to Import CSV file to Sqlite Database in Flutter way?

Tags: sqlite, csv, flutter, dart

I have been searching to import csv to database in flutter way. But unfortunately, I cannot find articles related to this case. So I wonder if there is a way to import csv to database. If yes, how can I achieve that? For my case, I open the file picker and want to import csv file. I can easily do it in Kotlin way but not in a flutter way. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: use https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite - most likely execute `db.insert` in a loop - one `insert` per row

Comment: I use sqlite, but how can I read contents and add them in sqlite database? In Kotlin I read with headLine(BufferedReader(file)) and remove "," and save in a array and insert to database. How can I achieve that way in Flutter since its been only 1 month that I started learning Flutter.

Comment: see `File.openRead()` and `LineSplitter`

Comment: OK, I will take a look

Comment: more here: https://fluttermaster.com/how-to-read-file-using-dart/ - i forgot that for small files you can use `File.readAsLines()`

Comment: btw, does it have to be csv file? why not a normal [sqlite dump](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-dump/)?

Comment: Yes it need to be CSV, because I need to import some csv files as Master to check Received Item.

Answer (score 6):

Well, it's not straightforward.

You'd normally use something like https://pub.dev/packages/csv or https://pub.dev/packages/spreadsheet_decoder in order to parse CSV.

So it'd look something like:

```
final input = new File('documents/file.csv').openRead();
```

Then convert it to the list:

```
final fields = await input.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(new CsvToListConverter()).toList();
```

After you did that, you'd normally have a function that is going to do a bulk update.

First, create a database

```
Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
    onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
  await db.execute(
      'CREATE TABLE Test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, value INTEGER, num REAL)');
});
```

Then you could use some helper method like mentioned here => https://stackoverflow.com/a/56507307/1737811 in order to populate the database fields with your result.

That way you'd pass your `tablename`, and of course your `List` containing the values from the CSV that you've just decoded.

Comment: Can you please tell me more about implementing some helper method? I don't get it.